# RestKit many-to-many mapping, how to?

Tags: ios, core-data, many-to-many, restkit

I'm working on my first RestKit app, and I use CoreData for local caching. In it I have a many-to-many relationship between Post <<--->> Category. The relationship is called posts, and categories.

In my Post JSON call I get id's for the categories like this: `{"post": [...] "categories":[1,4] [...]`, where 1 and 4 is the ids.

I have a custom `Post` model object that inherits from `NSManagedObject`, in it I have a property for categories, like this:

```
@interface Post : NSManagedObject

[...]
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *categories;
[...]
```

I do the same thing in a custom Category model object.

My mappings currently looks like this:

```
RKManagedObjectMapping *categoryMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Category class] inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.objectStore];
categoryMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"categoryId";
categoryMapping.rootKeyPath = @"categories";
[categoryMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"categoryId"];
[categoryMapping mapKeyPath:@"name" toAttribute:@"name"];
[...]


RKManagedObjectMapping* postMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Post class] inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.objectStore];

postMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"postId";
postMapping.rootKeyPath = @"post";
[postMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"postId"];
[...]
[postMapping mapKeyPath:@"created_at" toAttribute:@"createdAt"];
[...]
// Categories many-to-many.
[postMapping mapKeyPath:@"categories" toRelationship:@"categories"  withMapping:categoryMapping];
```

When I run this I get the error: `'[<__NSCFNumber 0x6c625e0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key id.'`

I would really appreciate if anyone could give me any clues on how to map this relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There error is because your JSON returns each category as a primary key, ie: a NSNumber. But your mapping expects an nested object (which will be transformed into a KVC object). When your map tries to access the property "id" on the KVC object (which is actually a NSNumber), it will crash like this.

I'm not sure if it will work, but you can try something like this:

```
RKManagedObjectMapping* categoryMapping = //something
categoryMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"categoryId";
[categoryMapping mapKeyPath: @"" toAttribute: @"categoryId"];

[..]

[postMapping mapKeyPath: @"categories" toRelationship: @"categories" withMapping: categoryMapping];
```

Normally, you would use the [RKManagedObjectMapping connectRelationship:withObjectForPrimaryKeyAttribute:] method, but I don't know if this will work on a many-to-many relationship. You may have to modify the source code to do this. The code to look at is inside [RKManagedObjectMappingOperation connectRelationship:].

Otherwise, if possible I would suggest you change your JSON source so the categories array is like this: "categories" : [{"categoryID: 1}, {"categoryID" : 4}]. If the source is not possible to change, you can modify the data manually using the delegate methods or the RKObjectLoader extension I have given below:

.h

```
typedef void(^RKObjectLoaderWillMapDataBlock)(id* mappableData);

@interface RKObjectLoader (Extended)

@property (nonatomic, copy) RKObjectLoaderWillMapDataBlock onWillMapData;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "RKObjectLoader+Extended.h"

#import <objc/runtime.h>

NSString* kOnWillMapDataKey = @"onWillMapData";

@implementation RKObjectLoader (Extended)

- (RKObjectLoaderWillMapDataBlock) onWillMapData {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &kOnWillMapDataKey);
}

- (void) setOnWillMapData:(RKObjectLoaderWillMapDataBlock) block {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &kOnWillMapDataKey, block, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY);
}

- (RKObjectMappingResult*)mapResponseWithMappingProvider:(RKObjectMappingProvider*)mappingProvider toObject:(id)targetObject inContext:(RKObjectMappingProviderContext)context error:(NSError**)error {
    id<RKParser> parser = [[RKParserRegistry sharedRegistry] parserForMIMEType:self.response.MIMEType];
    NSAssert1(parser, @"Cannot perform object load without a parser for MIME Type '%@'", self.response.MIMEType);

    // Check that there is actually content in the response body for mapping. It is possible to get back a 200 response
    // with the appropriate MIME Type with no content (such as for a successful PUT or DELETE). Make sure we don't generate an error
    // in these cases
    id bodyAsString = [self.response bodyAsString];
    RKLogTrace(@"bodyAsString: %@", bodyAsString);
    if (bodyAsString == nil || [[bodyAsString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]] length] == 0) {
        RKLogDebug(@"Mapping attempted on empty response body...");
        if (self.targetObject) {
            return [RKObjectMappingResult mappingResultWithDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.targetObject forKey:@""]];
        }

        return [RKObjectMappingResult mappingResultWithDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionary]];
    }

    id parsedData = [parser objectFromString:bodyAsString error:error];
    if (parsedData == nil && error) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Allow the delegate to manipulate the data
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(objectLoader:willMapData:)]) {
        parsedData = AH_AUTORELEASE([parsedData mutableCopy]);
        [(NSObject<RKObjectLoaderDelegate>*)self.delegate objectLoader:self willMapData:&parsedData];
    }

    if( self.onWillMapData ) {
        parsedData = AH_AUTORELEASE([parsedData mutableCopy]);
        self.onWillMapData(&parsedData);
    }

    RKObjectMapper* mapper = [RKObjectMapper mapperWithObject:parsedData mappingProvider:mappingProvider];
    mapper.targetObject = targetObject;
    mapper.delegate = (id<RKObjectMapperDelegate>)self;
    mapper.context = context;
    RKObjectMappingResult* result = [mapper performMapping];

    // Log any mapping errors
    if (mapper.errorCount > 0) {
        RKLogError(@"Encountered errors during mapping: %@", [[mapper.errors valueForKey:@"localizedDescription"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "]);
    }

    // The object mapper will return a nil result if mapping failed
    if (nil == result) {
        // TODO: Construct a composite error that wraps up all the other errors. Should probably make it performMapping:&error when we have this?
        if (error) *error = [mapper.errors lastObject];
        return nil;
    }

    return result;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks, decided to change the JSON to `"categories":[{"category_id":1},{"category_id":4}]`, do you know how and when I should populate the join table? I currently only fetch the categories.   Thanks!

Comment: What is a join table? This is actually another question.

Comment: Yes, thanks. A join table is the table between the two many-to-many entities, where primary keys from the two tables is stored. It actually populates this join table when I load posts, but then it also creates new rows in my Category model for some reason. Will probably ask another question for that issue. But changing the JSON seemed to help, no error no more. Thanks!

Comment: Asked a new question for the comment above here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227548/restkit-many-to-many-relationship-saves-new-rows-in-both-join-table-and-null-val.